# What is Buildship and is there a Gradle plugin for NetBeans?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, netbeans, buildship, niagara-4

Could someone explain this feature named "[Buildship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeyKO.jpg)" in the Eclipse IDE marketplace? Is this feature available for the Netbeans IDE?

Answer (score 3):

It is a plugin for Eclipse to provide integration with Gradle. It lets you perform Gradle related procedures from within the IDE.

E.g. You can easier import or start new projects configured with Gradle, the Gradle preferences menu allows you to choose which Gradle version will be used (the one installed in your OS or the project's wrapper), tasks view etc. There are some extra menus/buttons for easier access too. For a more thorough description, you can refer to the [plugin's page in Eclipse marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/buildship-gradle-integration) or the plugin's [Github](https://github.com/eclipse/buildship) page (it is open-source, as is Eclipse, as is Gradle itself).

It is included in the latest Eclipse versions, at least in the "for Java" and "for Enterprise Java" flavors of the IDE.

To avoid any possible confusion, there is:

- The *Buildship plugin* for integrating Gradle to the Eclipse IDE, adding extra functionality to the IDE itself.
- There is also the *["eclipse" plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html), used in the build.gradle* file of a project. This is a Gradle plugin that enables you to manipulate the files Eclipse uses to build your projects (.classpath, JDT settings etc) from within the buildscript using the Gradle DSL. You can use this plugin even if you are working in another IDE (so that the correct Eclipse files are created and another collaborating developer using Eclipse can correctly build your project).

These are two different plugins for different purposes.

I don't think "Buildship" itself is available for NetBeans since "Buildship" is the name for the Eclipse-specific plugin developed under the Eclipse github page.
For Netbeans exists this [plugin for Gradle integration](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project). (If you select Netbeans in gradle.org, it redirects you to the Netbeans plugin website. The plugin version there seems very old but when you open the github page you will see it is actively developed with the latest release in 12/2018).
However I haven't used Netbeans with Gradle and I can not provide any reliable info on how tight the integration is or if there are any other solutions.